# What does "low quality contributions" mean?

Tags: discussion

What does the the following message mean?

> This account is temporarily suspended because of low-quality contributions.

What does "low-quality contributions" mean? Does it mean too many "Please send teh codez/Google this for me" posts, or does it mean too many posts which are abusive? Or can it mean either?

Note: this is a general question, not a question about a specific suspension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you follow the link, you will get to this [blog post from 2009](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) which explains this in-depth:

> Our general strategy is to discourage specific problem behaviors, not
> individual users. But sometimes you just can’t seem to reach people,
> and it becomes necessary to place accounts in timed suspension.
>
> When users exhibit a pattern of either …
>
> ### No effort to learn and improve over time
>
> - This user does not put reasonable effort into the questions they ask of the community.
> - There is little or no evidence of this user learning over time, either in the topic itself or in the community norms on the site.
> - This user intentionally spams the site with the same question or very similar questions, over and over.
> - The user never gives anything back to the community, but only takes.
>
> ### Disruptive behavior
>
> - Other users tend to react poorly to this user’s contributions, posting negative responses in kind and generally causing a commotion.
> - There is a broad sense of community resentment over this user’s behavior, and they are frequently cited in discussion about the
>   community.
> - There is a dark storm cloud of moderator flags that seems to follow this user around wherever they go.
> - The moderators get email complaints about this user’s behavior.
> - This user makes overtly snide, rude, or hostile comments to their fellow users.
>
> … these problem behaviors have to be dealt with. When they aren’t, it
> takes up excessive moderator time that could be used for something
> more productive — and, even worse, these behaviors begin to **actively
> turn people away from our community, stunting its growth and harming
> everyone**.

To me, it seems that the criteria are purposefully broad. Any repeated behavior that hurts the community can result in a temporary ban. This obviously goes for abusive posts, but can also result from a large number of low quality posts which may not result in a ban on their own ([example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288758/why-did-i-get-suspended-a-year-for-asking-too-many-questions)).

Comment: This is all correct. The reasons are actually very specific, but the public facing reasons are kept generic on purpose to protect the privacy of the user in question.